# Two mutable borrows with zero cost

Tags: rust

I want to have an API that would allow sound from multiple channels interleaved with each other (as they usually do in audio format) being written to corresponding number of sinks (`io::Write`). It would be really nice IMHO if in case one wants to mux all channels into one sink, all `s?he` needed to do is to pass the same `sink` instead of different ones.

The following code doesn’t work

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn write<W1: Write, W2: Write>(data: &[u8], mut w1: W1, mut w2: W2) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    for (byte, i) in data.iter().zip((0..2).cycle()) {
        if i == 0 {
            w1.write(&[*byte])?;
        } else {
            w2.write(&[*byte])?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut w1 = Vec::new();
    let mut w2 = Vec::new();
    write(&[1, 2, 3, 4], &mut w1, &mut w2);
    dbg!((w1, w2));
    let mut w1 = Vec::new();
    write(&[1, 2, 3, 4], &mut w1, &mut w1);
    dbg!(w1);
}
```

I understand why Rust is disallowing that. But I still wonder how to do that in Rust more or less zero-cost. Of course I could use unsafe and raw pointers, but is there something in std already?. I’ve tried to use `RefCell`, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Perhaps change the signature of `write` so that the `w2` parameter is `Option<W2>` and then use `w1` in its place if the caller passes `None`?

Comment: Or rather have a separate function for the case where "both" sinks are the same. There doesn't seem to be much of a point in trying to fit two incompatible plugs in the same socket.

Comment: You can do something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d76a888f29054c638316099bea3d9413

Comment: But @E_net4 makes a good point.

Comment: @E_net4 I don’t agree with you. Aside from rust borrowing rules there’s nothing incompatible and it also allows to stay DRY.

Comment: @user1685095 But they _are_ incompatible, as passing two mutable references to the same value is fundamentally against the language's memory model and would result in undefined behavior if that had been forced. Feel free to disagree, but the trade-off seems evident here. Either this `write` function is made more complicated to accommodate the possible scenario of passing two values referring to the same sink, possibly with inefficiencies or delicate `unsafe` trickery, or we have two simpler functions which compose and optimize well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a trait to allow more flexibility on what you pass to the function.

```
trait MutPair {
    type A;
    type B;
    fn mut_a(&mut self) -> &mut Self::A;
    fn mut_b(&mut self) -> &mut Self::B;
}
```

You can implement this for a pair of mutable references but also for a single reference.

```
impl<'a, 'b, T, U> MutPair for (&'a mut T, &'b mut U) {
    type A = T;
    type B = U;
    fn mut_a(&mut self) -> &mut Self::A {
        &mut self.0
    }
    fn mut_b(&mut self) -> &mut Self::B {
        &mut self.1
    }
}

impl<T> MutPair for &mut T {
    type A = T;
    type B = T;
    fn mut_a(&mut self) -> &mut Self::A {
        self
    }
    fn mut_b(&mut self) -> &mut Self::B {
        self
    }
}
```

Change `write` to use the trait:

```
fn write<M>(data: &[u8], mut writers: M) -> Result<(), io::Error> 
where
    M: MutPair,
    M::A: Write,
    M::B: Write
{
    for (byte, i) in data.iter().zip((0..2).cycle()) {
        if i == 0 {
            writers.mut_a().write(&[*byte])?;
        } else {
            writers.mut_b().write(&[*byte])?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

You can now call `write` with two different references:

```
write(&[1, 2, 3, 4], (&mut w1, &mut w2));
```

Or just one:

```
write(&[1, 2, 3, 4], &mut w1);
```

---

Having said that, @E_net4's suggestion is worth thinking about: just having a different method for when you only want to use the same writer could end being a lot simpler.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn’t answer my question. I understand that I can complicate an API with introducing new traits etc. That’s not the problem. I want to know how to "bypass" Rust borrowing rules with `RefCell` or something of a kind.

Comment: @user1685095 I don't think it's better than introducing a trait, but you can use shared references with `RefCell`.

Comment: @user1685095 `RefCell` is certainly possible, but it will make it more complicated to use and incur some runtime cost: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2092579656a0a682c89dd47a20dd262b)

Comment: I realize now, that my question might be only solvable with UnsafeCell or heterogeneous lists.

Comment: `RefCell` and `UnsafeCell` are not zero cost though, which was a requirement of your question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you object to this answer because you want the `write` function's parameters be exactly the type given? That isn't possible (soundly), regardless of unsafe shenanigans, because two mutable references to the same data are not allowed to even exist at the same time.

Comment: @PeterHall UnsafeCell doesn't cost anything I think it's just "black box" and tell compiler "trust me bro"

Comment: @Stargateur That depends on your definition of "zero cost" :) In terms of performance, UnsafeCell has an impact on what optimisations can be done. Sometimes this is pretty significant. But it also can have a productivity/maintainability cost because invariance tends to spread...

Comment: oh yeah of course, that the same problem with char in C about aliasing this disallow so much optimisation